# SetState of an array of Objects in React

Tags: reactjs, immutability, setstate

Ok, so I'm so frustrated finding the right solution so I'm posting the problem here. Giving an answer would help me a lot, coz I'm stuck!

the state tree looks like this

```
this.state = {
      itemList : [{
                    _id : 1234,
                   description : 'This the description',
                   amount : 100
                    }, {
                    _id : 1234,
                   description : 'This the description',
                   amount : 100
                    }],
     }
```

The problems are :

1. can not update any specific key in the Object of the array according
   to the _id
2. The previous state should remain intact

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### answered March 25 2018

This is how you would use setState and prevstate to update a certain attribute of an object in your data structure.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    itemList: prevState.itemList.map(
    obj => (obj._id === 1234 ? Object.assign(obj, { description: "New Description" }) : obj)
  )
}));
```

### answered Dec 12 2019 (REACT HOOKS)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      username: '141451',
      password: 'password',
      favoriteFood: 'pizza',
    },
    {
      username: '15151',
      password: '91jf7jn38f8jn3',
      favoriteFood: 'beans'
    }
  ]);
  return (
    <div>
    {data.map(user => {
      return (
        <div onClick={() => {
          setData([...data].map(object => {
            if(object.username === user.username) {
              return {
                ...object,
                favoriteFood: 'Potatos',
                someNewRandomAttribute: 'X'
              }
            }
            else return object;
          }))
        }}>
        {JSON.stringify(user) + '\n'}
        </div>
      )
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @Omar I need to update the whole objects in the array ??

Comment: Then just do const updatedValues = array.map(item => { return { ...item, updatedKey: ‘value’ } })

Comment: `Object.assign(obj` mutates the current state object which is an anti-pattern in React. `Object.assign({}, obj` would correctly create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

to update state constructed like this you will have to find index of element you want to update, copy the array and change found index.

it's easier and more readable if you keep list of records as object, with id as a key and record as a value.

Comment: Then how to iterate all the objects ?

Comment: if you're using lodash or ramda in your app, you can use that, or you can use Object.keys(). i usually use redux to keep data like this and use reselect, so my selectors return arrays

Answer (score -3):

The only way to do this will be to copy itemList, modify it, and set the state to it.

```
update() {
   let itemList = this.state.itemList.slice();
   //update it
   this.setState({ itemList });
}
```

Comment: `let itemList = this.state.itemList;`. If you modify `itemList` after this, you are mutating the state.

Comment: Not when you slice it.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu you're wrong slice creates a copy

Comment: Since the post was edited, it's obvious my comment referred to the initial  code.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu didnt see the edit, did just now though

Answer (score -3):

*Best way to update data into an array of objects*

`onChange={ (e) => this.setState({formData: { ...this.state.formData, 'plan_id': e.target.value}})}`